# Modifying variables used in givens

Tags: theano

This is the definition of the train_model function.

```
train_model = theano.function(
    [index],
    cost,
    updates=updates,
    givens={
        x: train_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: train_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)
```

Say I modify `training_set_x` after this definition, which value will reflect in givens `x`? The old value or the new modified value?

In other words, when when a theano function is compiled, are the variables used in the expressions copied or just a reference is given?

Please do correct me if my question is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My experiments have yielded that such variables are passed by value while compiling the theano function ie any change in the value of the variable after the function is compiled doesn't have any effect on the behaviour of the function.

Say I define my function like this

```
x=T.lscalar('x')
y=T.lscalar('y')
z=x+y
i=T.lscalar('i')

a=theano.shared(np.asarray([1,2,3,4]))
f=function([i],z,givens={x:a[i],y:a[i]})
```

Then `f`'s behaviour is as follows

```
>>> f(0)
array(2)
>>> f(1)
array(4)
>>> f(2)
array(6)
>>> f(3)
array(8)
```

Now if I modify `a` as follows

```
a=theano.shared(np.asarray([0,0,0,0]))
```

Then the **behaviour of the function remains the same**.